# I made a "public void" function, how do I now call it in another activity?

Tags: java, android

I've never used public before but now I need a function in multiple activities so instead of creating the method in every single activity, I just made it public so that it is accessible to every activity. But how do I now use it? If I simply call the method in another activity it doesn't recognize it and it doesn't give me an option to import it.

This is the method:

```
public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
          = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use `isNetworkAvailable` from multiple activities, you shouldn't put it in one activity and then use it from another. Instead, you should create a **utility class**. A utility class is usually a class with static helper methods you can use across your app.

For example:

```
package com.example.util;

public static class NetworkUtils {
    public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
              = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
}
```

Then, in an activity, use it like this:

```
NetworkUtils.isNetworkAvailable(this)
```

... or if you're inside a fragment:

```
NetworkUtils.isNetworkAvailable(getActivity())
```

... or if you're just inside some callback:

```
NetworkUtils.isNetworkAvailable(MyActivity.this)
```

Comment: Exactly the kind of answer I needed, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

That is an instance method, and as such, you need an object over which to call it (an instance of your child `Activity`). This means you will need to pass the object instance if the class calling it is not the one containing the method. That's not a very good idea. Consider making it `static`:

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager) {
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

Then you can call without any object instance and by class name

```
YourActivityClass.isNetworkAvailable((ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE));
```

Also consider moving this method to a *helper* class.

Oh and your method is not `public void`, it's `public boolean`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can move this to a utility class, and define the method as static, sample code as below(need add necessary importing)

```
public class Utility {
    public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context mc) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
          = (ConnectivityManager) mc.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two different scenarios:

### First Option

is to create a static method similar to below in anywhere(in a util class etc.):

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context ctx) {
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = ((ConnectivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

### Second Option

is to create an `abstract` `Activity` such as:

```
package com.example.activities;

public abstract class MyActivity extends Activity{
    public final boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = ((ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
}
```

and make sure your activities extending `MyActivity`. So your activities can use `isNetworkAvailable` method at will.